# How to save large files in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to upload a 10Mb file in mysql database, the datatype of the field is LONGBLOB and I have already configured the max allowed packet in my.ini file but I still can't save the file. Files lower than 10Mb can be saved in the database so I'm wondering why it can't be saved. Are there any other places I need to check to get this to work?

```
max_allowed_packet = 1024M
```

This is how I get the data:

```
$data = $dbLink->real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']));
```

Comment: Save the file in your server and just linked them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do that

TEXT and BLOB is stored off the table with the table just having a pointer to the location of the actual storage.

When a table has TEXT or BLOB columns, the table can't be stored in memory. This means every query (which doesn't hit cache) has to access the file system - which is orders of magnitude slower than the memory.

Instead save the path of the file in DB.

Answer (score 5):

Don't do that, save the file on your server and than reference it in your db, otherwise you'll end up with a really slow db in no time

Comment: will saving files on the database also slow down access for other data stored in the database?

Comment: +1 for the more concise answer, as there are several reasons not to do this. Another one is the increased chance of DB corruption, and memory fragmentation.

Comment: @Kyoka, yes, if the files are stored in the same table as the data you are trying to access. When you perform a query, the DB will fetch all of your data (lets not consider paging atm) hence slowing down your select query. Not to mention the increased network traffic

Comment: @KyokaSuigetsu in my experience, yes, it's an absolut anti-pattern. I inherited some apps thatsaved files on the db and i always had to refactor them.

Comment: @Simon: I'm not really the one who can decide whether to save it on the db or on the file system. My superior wants the files to be saved in the db because he seems to had problems with files before, but thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @KyokaSuigetsu then try to convince your boss by doing some benchmarks: upload 13gb of data to your db and then run some sample queries and benchamrk those queries with a db that's exactly the same minus the files.

Comment: The only thing I can stress is to try and change his thinking. Trust me, you will encounter more problems this way than storing files. Its not called a Filesystem (NTFS that is) for nothing, and similarly its not called a Filebase, but a Database.

Comment: @Kyoka, MySQL (even most DB's out there) weren't designed to store big files. Eventually, you will run into corruption issues with storing that much data in you DB - the problem is, you just wont know when. You have already encountered a problem with this method (storing files larger than 10MB) and trust me, that is only the start. Backup times will be longer, queries will be longer.

Answer (score 3):

The best way would be not to save binary files in the database at all.

Answer (score 3):

While there are reasonable cases, like when storing small images ( though you can actually make similar functionality like `ROLLBACK` with filesystem too ), usually it is an exceptionally bad idea.

Files should be stored on the disk. And in case of large-scale systems: on a separate servers, dedicated for this purpose.

### P.S.

You should stop using the outdated `mysql_*` functions. They are more then 10 years old and are not maintained anymore. Even the process for deprecation [has begun](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). instead you should [**learn**](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) how to utilize prepared statements with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).